# How can I set the title of a cluetop tooltip from ajax callback when sticky: true?

Tags: jquery, ajax, title, cluetip

I am using [cluetip plugin which](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/) is great. I am populating the plugin using Ajax but I can't anywhere (in the documentation or examples) on how to set the title from an ajax callback.

Is updating the title from ajax supported in cluetip?

### UPDATE NOTE:

So the suggestions given below work in the sense that they can create a title but the close button doesn't show up in the title in this case. See image below.

[image]

Comment: As far as I can see the [clueTip demo page](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/) has plenty of examples for this (from example 2. onwards)

Comment: @Tomm - there is no example with ajax and a title.

Comment: Have look at this forum post: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/cluetip-how-to-set-the-title-from-an-external-page-ajax

Comment: @Tomm - i tried that post but it doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: @leora - have you tried my answer below? dose it works for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, It is pretty easy if you see from a simple angle.

First thing to note, would be that all the cluetips in the document, use only **one** mark-up layout to show all the tips. Every time a new cluetip is triggered, it only updates its mark-up layout and shows it.

#### Lets see an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/yFnNk/1/) of how to work around with what you are trying

---

I used the demo for this. So the mark-up is:

<sub>Note:I am using two cluetips to simulate a case having multiple cluetips</sub>

```
<a class="title" title="hello" href="http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/ajax3.html" rel="http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/ajax3.html">This example</a>

<a class="basic" href="http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/ajax.html" rel="http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/ajax.html">Basic</a>
```

Lets make a small change in the styles, so that it aligns correctly

```
.cluetip-close { float: right; margin-top: -40px; }
```

Now, our Script, for both the clue tips.

```
  var title;
  $('a.title').cluetip({
      closePosition: 'top',
      sticky: true,
      closeText: '<img src="http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/cross.png" alt="close" width="16" height="16" />Close',            
      ajaxCache: false,
      ajaxSettings:  {
        success: function(data) {
            title = "Your new Title";            
            $(this).attr("title", title); //just set the title for consistency
        }
      },
      onShow : function(ct,c) {
          $(".cluetip-title").text(title); //update the title class with the title
      }
  });

  $('a.basic').cluetip(); //While definning another tip, it is NOT affected by previous one
```

#### It's DONE

Although the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/yFnNk/1/) might not show it. I have tested it and **it works**.

Answer (score 2):

Cluetip caches the title when it is first created. As a result, you have to change it in the onShow option. Trying to change it in the ajaxProcess step will lead to your changes being overwritten.

However, you could use the ajax setting option to get the title you want and store that title in a variable.

Keep in mind that cluetip caches the ajax result by default. You can set ajaxCache: false to change that.

Here is some example code

```
var title;
$('a.clue').cluetip({
    ajaxSettings:  {
        success: function(data) {
            // GET Title here
            title = 'new title';
        }
    },
    ajaxCache: false,
    onShow : function(ct,c) {
         $("#cluetip-title").text(title);
    }
});
```

You could also use the ajaxProcess option but you would need to make sure you called the default for that option to ensure that it strips script and style tags.

Comment: i have multiple tooltips on the page so i dont think $("#cluetip-title").text(title); is going to work

Comment: i have added a screenshot to the question to highlight what i see

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a jsFiddle or example? I deleted the code I was testing this with ages ago.

From what I can see there is only one 'clue-tip' per page. However, looking at the demo I think the clue-tip title is a h3.cluetip-title not an id.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$('a.basic').cluetip({
    ajaxProcess: function(data) {
        // Suppose the data come with the following structure:
        data = { title: "Another title", body: "Blah blah blah blah" };

        $(this).attr("title", data.title);
        return data.body;
    },
    onShow: function(ct, c) {
        ct.find(".cluetip-title").text(
            $(this).attr("title")
        );
    }
});
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/A9EQ5/20/

Comment: the issue here is that if you have sticky:true, the close button doesn't show up on the title but instead it shows up on a line below it.  Is there any workaround for that ??

Comment: i have added a screenshot to the question to highlight what i see

Comment: I think the problem with the close button is not relevant to your initial question. I can't see how setting the title the way I suggest could mess up the close button.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $('a.basic').cluetip({
      sticky: true,
      closePosition: 'title',
      ajaxCache: false,
      ajaxProcess: function(data) {
        data = {title: "AjaxTitleGoesHere", body:"AjaxBodyGoesHere"};
        $(this).attr("title", data.title);
        return data.body;
      },
      onShow: function(ct, c) {
        ct.find(".cluetip-title").append(
            $(this).attr("title")
        );
      }
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always hide the title and simulate it using the ajax response.